# To replace one word in first line with another in 2nd line in linux with sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a log with the following texts. I need to replace GX81CBCCONVCH10 with the string GX4APDOCUGRLK10 / GX4DODOCGRPGT30 /.. in next line. And then delete the next two lines.
Can anyone help with any sed or awk command to do that. Or any python scripts.

I was replacing in vim with the following command but it does not work in sed.
`:s/\(^.*\)GX81CBCCONVCH10\(.*\n\)\(.*EXT;\)\(.*;.*;.*;\)\(.*\)\(;.*;.*\n.*RTC.*\)/\1\5\2/g`

Log:

```
20220812 090258078;1;2727;SVC;GX81CBCCONVCH10;;10.115.48.238;1.015;0.023;0.996;0.014;4096;820;1;0.995;3;0.009
20220812 090258078;1;2727;EXT;SwitchOAIntf;0.995;0.000;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;P;RIDD08B825RQ11DC
20220812 090258078;1;2727;RTC;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;1;0;0.00060;0.00000

20220812 090303106;1;2727;SVC;GX81CBCCONVCH10;;10.115.48.238;1.119;0.028;1.106;0.018;4096;1084;1;1.105;3;0.003
20220812 090303106;1;2727;EXT;SwitchOAIntf;1.105;0.000;GX4DODOCGRPGT30;P;RIDO2PCD35RQ11DC
20220812 090303106;1;2727;RTC;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;1;0;0.00065;0.00000

20220812 090308239;1;2727;SVC;GX81CBCCONVCH10;;10.115.48.238;0.896;0.031;0.883;0.021;4096;1084;1;0.881;3;0.003
20220812 090308239;1;2727;EXT;SwitchOAIntf;0.881;0.000;GX4DODOCGRPGT50;P;RIDWNKFI35RQ11DC
20220812 090308239;1;2727;RTC;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;1;0;0.00060;0.00000

20220812 090309137;1;2727;SVC;GX81CBCCONVCH10;;10.115.48.238;0.878;0.022;0.868;0.015;4096;820;1;0.867;3;0.003
20220812 090309137;1;2727;EXT;SwitchOAIntf;0.867;0.000;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;P;RIDZACDJ35RQ11DC
20220812 090309137;1;2727;RTC;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;1;0;0.00060;0.00000
```

The output should be like:

```
20220812 090258078;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;1.015;0.023;0.996;0.014;4096;820;1;0.995;3;0.009

20220812 090303106;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT30;;10.115.48.238;1.119;0.028;1.106;0.018;4096;1084;1;1.105;3;0.003

20220812 090308239;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT50;;10.115.48.238;0.896;0.031;0.883;0.021;4096;1084;1;0.881;3;0.003

20220812 090309137;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;0.878;0.022;0.868;0.015;4096;820;1;0.867;3;0.003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/(GX81CBCCONVCH)10/{s//\130/;N;N;P;d}' file
```

Match `GX81CBCCONVCH10` and replace `10` with `30`, append the next two lines and print the first only.

Edit: Misunderstood the question, perhaps:

```
sed -E '/SVC/{N;N;s/GX81CBCCONVCH10(.*)\n.*EXT(;[^;]*){3};([^;]*).*\n.*RTC.*/\3\1/}' file
```

Comment: No the whole string are different. So just replacing 10 to 30 will not work.

Comment: @SubhartheeDutta see edit

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} (NR%4)==2{rep=$8; $0=prev; $5=rep; print} {prev=$0}' file
20220812 090258078;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;1.015;0.023;0.996;0.014;4096;820;1;0.995;3;0.009
20220812 090303106;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT30;;10.115.48.238;1.119;0.028;1.106;0.018;4096;1084;1;1.105;3;0.003
20220812 090308239;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT50;;10.115.48.238;0.896;0.031;0.883;0.021;4096;1084;1;0.881;3;0.003
20220812 090309137;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;0.878;0.022;0.868;0.015;4096;820;1;0.867;3;0.003
```

or if you really do want the output lines separated by blank lines then either this which will also produce a blank line at the end of the output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"; ORS="\n\n"} (NR%4)==2{rep=$8; $0=prev; $5=rep; print} {prev=$0}' file
20220812 090258078;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;1.015;0.023;0.996;0.014;4096;820;1;0.995;3;0.009

20220812 090303106;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT30;;10.115.48.238;1.119;0.028;1.106;0.018;4096;1084;1;1.105;3;0.003

20220812 090308239;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT50;;10.115.48.238;0.896;0.031;0.883;0.021;4096;1084;1;0.881;3;0.003

20220812 090309137;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;0.878;0.022;0.868;0.015;4096;820;1;0.867;3;0.003
```

or this which won't:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} (NR%4)==2{rep=$8; $0=prev; $5=rep; print sep $0; sep=ORS} {prev=$0}' file
20220812 090258078;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;1.015;0.023;0.996;0.014;4096;820;1;0.995;3;0.009

20220812 090303106;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT30;;10.115.48.238;1.119;0.028;1.106;0.018;4096;1084;1;1.105;3;0.003

20220812 090308239;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT50;;10.115.48.238;0.896;0.031;0.883;0.021;4096;1084;1;0.881;3;0.003

20220812 090309137;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;0.878;0.022;0.868;0.015;4096;820;1;0.867;3;0.003
```

Comment: This is not generic. It has worked for those lines but has messed up other logs.

Comment: Then those other logs don't look like the example you provided. This solution is 100% "generic" for log files formatted as you show in your question as it doesn't care about the values in your data, only the order of lines and their `;`-separated position in each line and it's also 100% portable to all Unix boxes regardless of which versions of tools exist there. If this isn't what you need for your real data then you should ask a new question with more truly representative sample input/output that includes cases where this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/([^G]*)GX81CBCCONVCH10([^\n]*)\n[^G]*(GX[^;]*)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*/\1\3\2/g' input_file
20220812 090258078;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;1.015;0.023;0.996;0.014;4096;820;1;0.995;3;0.009

20220812 090303106;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT30;;10.115.48.238;1.119;0.028;1.106;0.018;4096;1084;1;1.105;3;0.003

20220812 090308239;1;2727;SVC;GX4DODOCGRPGT50;;10.115.48.238;0.896;0.031;0.883;0.021;4096;1084;1;0.881;3;0.003

20220812 090309137;1;2727;SVC;GX4APDOCUGRLK10;;10.115.48.238;0.878;0.022;0.868;0.015;4096;820;1;0.867;3;0.003
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `sed` command (that should work in any `sed`):

```
sed '/^$/d; N; s/\(\([^;]*;\)\{4\}\)[^;]*\(;.*\)\n\([^;]*;\)\{7\}\([^;]*\).*/\1\5\3/p; N; d' file
```